# MySQL - autoincrement not working

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I migrated existing DB (by SQL export/import via phpmyadmin) from 1 server to another. On new one I cannot add any new rows, either via application nor via phpmyadmin. Only one row is created with id 0, there is no auto - increment. AI is also not specified on tables on DB where it works OK.

I believe this must have to do with verion/settings of mysql.

sql_mode is on working server:
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

on not working is empty. I check this via phpmyadmin->variables, in my.cnf sql_mode is not mentioned on either server.

Mysql/php/nginx version:
Working:
 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
nginx/1.10.3
PHP version: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Not working:
5.5.59-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
nginx/1.12.2
PHP version: 7.0.27-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Any suggestions please.

Comment: You are trying to import a 5.7 database to a 5.5 server. It's unlikely that there were no problems. phpmyadmin by default will add the indexes (including the primary keys/autoincrement ones) at the end of the script, and the script probably didn't reach that point due to some error, so check the migration result for any errors. If you do not think this is the issue, please add the result of `show create table yourtablename` from both servers (or compare it yourself).

Comment: I actually ended up installing 5.7 and import db again which seems to have sorted this problem out